# TypeError at /polls/ context must be a dict rather than RequestContext

Tags: python, django, pycharm

This is `view.py` tab of my poll app in django. I can't debug the error: `Type Error: context must be a dict rather than RequestContext.` It is taken from the 6th video of a YouTube collection of 'my first django app' from the channel 'The Codex'. Please help?

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader, RequestContext
from .models import Question

def index(request):
    latest_questions = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'latest_questions': latest_questions
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))

def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("This is the detail view of the question: %s" %question_id)

def results(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("These are the results of the question: %s" %question_id)

def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("Vote on question: %s" %question_id)
```

Comment: Did you bother reading the official doc for your Django version before posting ?

Answer (score 0):

```
def index(request):
    latest_questions = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = {
        'request': request,
        'latest_questions': latest_questions
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

but

```
def index(request):
    latest_questions = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', {
            ''latest_questions': latest_questions
        })
```

is much better.

The usage of that video is old,if you are a newbee,I recommend you to study Django1.11 directly.Doc of django 1.11 is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same tutorial series and had the same problem. 
Instead of using RequestContext like this

```
 context = RequestContext(request,{
    'latest_questions': latest_questions
})
```

Use this dictionary instead

```
context = {
    'latest_questions': latest_questions,
}
```

I got this off of the Django documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead of yours.

```
def index(request):
    latest_questions = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_questions': latest_questions}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

Comment: You may want to explain why this solves the problem: ["Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)